# * and + behaving differently in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"ange134".match(/\d+/)       // result =>  134
"ange134".match(/\d*/)       // result =>  ""     //expected 134
```

In the above cases, `+` behaves okay, by being greedy.

But why is `/\d*/` not returning the same thing?

Comment: `\d*` matches the zero-length string before "ange". Greediness won’t change the fact that the first match is returned.

Comment: For the first part, answer should be 134, I guess.

Comment: Isn’t * greedy like +

Comment: `"ange134".match(/\d*/g);`

Comment: @AnkurMarwaha, look at the zero length number before `ange134`. The regex matches that. When you make it global, it matches the zero length number string after each alphabet, until it finds 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
"ange134".match(/\d+/)       // result =>  123
```

In the above case `\d+` makes sure that there has got to be at least one digit which may be followed by more, thus when the scanning begins and it finds "a" at the beginning it still keeps searching for digits as the condition is not met.

```
"ange134".match(/\d*/)       // result =>  ""     //expected 123
```

However in the above case, `\d*` implies that **zero** or more occurrence of digit. So when the scanning begins and when it finds "a" the condition is met (**which is zero occurrence of digit**)... therefore you are getting empty result set.

You may put global flag `/g` to make it keep searching for all result. See this [link](https://regex101.com/r/qMX6WA/1/) to understand how the behavior changes with global flag. Try to turn it on and off to understand it better.

```js
console.log("ange134".match(/\d*/));
console.log("ange134".match(/\d*$/));
console.log("ange134".match(/\d*/g));
console.log("134ange".match(/\d*/));   // this will return 134 as that is the first match that it gets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"ange134".match(/\d*/);
```

Means "match a number character 0 or more times".  As Ryan pointed out above, an empty string satisfies this regex.  Try:

```
"ange134".match(/\d*$/);
```

and you can see that it does in fact work - just needs some context if your goal is to match the **`134`** part of that string.

Answer (score 0):

```
"ange134".match(/\d*/) //means 0 or more times, and this match in the first
//letter (because it "returns false") because you aren't using global flag that search in the whole string
```

if you want it to work then use global flag:

```
"ange134".match(/\d*/g)
```

or use your first correct option without a flag:

```
"ange134".match(/\d+/)
```

in this link there is an explanation of why it match the first "a" letter: https://regex101.com/r/3ItllY/1/